# How can I solve Vue.js original tag error in index,html tagl?

Tags: html, vue.js, vim

### what I want

want to study vue.js framework in Vim.
Using this book
[https://cr-vue.mio3io.com/guide/chapter1.html#繰り返しの描画](https://cr-vue.mio3io.com/guide/chapter1.html#%E7%B9%B0%E3%82%8A%E8%BF%94%E3%81%97%E3%81%AE%E6%8F%8F%E7%94%BB)

### Problem

- Vue tag is not recogonized and do not work in browser.

[image: warn]

### Tried

- used `v-bind:key` and set id='app' to  but did not work.
- searched my `.vimrc` and escaped syntastatic, but it 
  did not solve.
  https://github.com/kaede0902/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc
- searched issue and found this, but I cannot understand 
  where to write the vimscript.
  https://github.com/htacg/tidy-html5/issues/569

How should I solve the Problem? Plz help me.

```html
<title>for vue</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

<ol>
    <li v-for="item in list" >{{item}}</li>
</ol>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10"></script>
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
                    list: ['apple','banana','stew',]
                }
    })
</script>
```

- commenting all Neobundle out did not stop warning.
- `filetype plugin indent on` out only stopped warning.

```
language C
set noswapfile "Pretend to make .swap
" 15:51 06-15, 15:52

set encoding=utf-8
"#####表示設定#####
set number "行番号を表示する
set title "編集中のファイル名を表示
set showmatch "括弧入力時の対応する括弧を表示
syntax on "コードの色分け
syntax enable " 構文に色を付ける

"##Tab Settings"
set expandtab " タブ入力を複数の空白入力に置き換える
set tabstop=4 " 画面上でタブ文字が占める幅
set softtabstop=4 " 連続した空白に対してタブキーやバックスペースキーでカーソルが動く幅
set autoindent " 改行時に前の行のインデントを継続する
set smartindent " 改行時に前の行の構文をチェックし次の行のインデントを増減する
set shiftwidth=4 " smartindentで増減する幅
set listchars=tab:\ \ ,trail:_  " Not EOL:, end of line to nothing but last space  

"List setting"
set list
set virtualedit=block
set whichwrap=b,s,[,],<,>
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set wildmenu

" clipboard setting, copy paste yank
set clipboard=unnamed

" Search Setting
set hlsearch
set ignorecase "大文字/小文字の区別なく検索する
set smartcase "検索文字列に大文字が含まれている場合は区別して検索する
set wrapscan "検索時に最後まで行ったら最初に戻
filetype off

" ### 表示設定 ###
set laststatus=2 " ステータスラインを常に表示
set showmode " 現在のモードを表示

set showcmd " 打ったコマンドをステータスラインの下に表示
set ruler " ステータスラインの右側にカーソルの現在位置を表示する


" ### START PlUG-IN ###
if has('vim_starting')
    " 初回起動時のみruntimepathにNeoBundleのパスを指定する
    set runtimepath+=~/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim/

    " If NeoBundle is Not installed, clone that.
    if !isdirectory(expand("~/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim/"))
        echo "install NeoBundle..."
        :call system("git clone git://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim ~/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim")
    endif
endif

call neobundle#begin(expand('~/.vim/bundle/'))

" ### NEO BUNDLE Plugins ###
NeoBundleFetch 'Shougo/neobundle.vim' " ADMIN ALL NEOBUNDLE

NeoBundle 'Shougo/vimproc.vim', {
\ 'build' : {
\     'windows' : 'tools\\update-dll-mingw',
\     'cygwin' : 'make -f make_cygwin.mak',
\     'mac' : 'make',
\     'linux' : 'make',
\     'unix' : 'gmake',
\    },
\}

" `NeoBundle 'vim-scripts/twilight'
NeoBundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree' " Enable NerdTreee
NeoBundle 'mattn/emmet-vim' " html:5 で補完.
NeoBundle 'itchyny/lightline.vim' " status line表示内容強化
NeoBundle 'Yggdroot/indentLine' " インデントの可視化
NeoBundle 'cohama/lexima.vim' " Complete the parental
NeoBundle 'thinca/vim-quickrun' " Complete the parental
NeoBundle 'syntastic.git' " annoying in html img
NeoBundle 'Quramy/vim-js-pretty-template'
NeoBundle 'Shougo/neocomplcache' 
NeoBundle 'Shougo/neosnippet' 
NeoBundle 'Shougo/neosnippet-snippets' 
NeoBundle 'surround.vim' "Surround by v and ctrl S
NeoBundle 'iamcco/mathjax-support-for-mkdp' " .md prev
NeoBundle 'iamcco/markdown-preview.vim' " .md prev

"----------------------------------------------------------
call neobundle#end()
" ファイルタイプ別のVimプラグイン/インデントを有効にする
filetype plugin indent on

" 未インストールがあるかチェック
NeoBundleCheck

" PathoGen Settings
execute pathogen#infect()
" styntatic settings
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0

""
" PHP Lint 
nmap ,l :call PHPLint()<CR>
"
"  PHPLint
"  
map H ^
map L $
"  @author halt feits <halt.feits at gmail.com>
"  
function PHPLint()
    let result = system( &ft . ' -l ' . bufname("") )
    echo result
endfunction

" keymapping settings ----------------
" Toggle NerdTree by ctrl l
map <silent> <C-l> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
" insert to normal by jj
imap jj <Esc>
" esc esc to noh
nnoremap <Esc><Esc> :nohlsearch<CR>
" H, L to ^, $
map H ^
map L $
" ?
nnoremap <C-j> }
nnoremap <C-k> {


" Console log from insert mode; Puts focus inside parentheses
imap cll console.log();<Esc>==f(a

" ## NeoSnippet Settings
" Plugin key-mappings.
" Note: It must be "imap" and "smap".  It uses <Plug> mappings.
imap <C-k>     <Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)
smap <C-k>     <Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)
xmap <C-k>     <Plug>(neosnippet_expand_target)

" SuperTab like snippets behavior.
" Note: It must be "imap" and "smap".  It uses <Plug> mappings.
imap <expr><TAB>
\ pumvisible() ? "\<C-n>" :
\ neosnippet#expandable_or_jumpable() ?
\    "\<Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)" : "\<TAB>"
smap <expr><TAB> neosnippet#expandable_or_jumpable() ?
\ "\<Plug>(neosnippet_expand_or_jump)" : "\<TAB>"

" For conceal markers.
if has('conceal')
  set conceallevel=2 concealcursor=niv
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

did you set `id="app"` to bind vue object and html?
I don't think it is binding.

```html
<title>for vue</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

<div id="app">
  <ol>
    <li v-for="item in list" >{{item}}</li>
  </ol>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10"></script>
<script>
    var app = new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
                    list: ['apple','banana','stew',]
                }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you it worked in browser,  but vim error Waning did not disappear.